# Where should I ask about the importance of exactness of floating point modulus?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a technical question:

I want to know why/where/when the exactness of floating point modulus (fmod / remainder) matters.

It's not about programming, I know how to program it.
It's more about marketing, because I'd like to replace naive implementation found in most Smalltalk dialects by a standard conforming one.
Adhering to standards and providing state of the art floating point in Smalltalk is my first goal.
However, I anticipate that adhering to standard will not be enough to convince my peers to change things, so explaining in which circumstances that would really matter would help a lot. I could not find a good example so far.

Is there a site where I could ask such question?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the link! so do you suggest ComputerScience? There does not seem to be many questions tagged floating-point

Comment: Thanks all, I took a chance at http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24362/why-does-floating-point-modulus-exactness-matters